# Supported Hardware in Windows Media Foundation

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I could not find a list of supported hardware or criterias for support for windows media foundation.
Basically I need the following streams/plugins, which i use in my wmf application

- HDMI video input via a graphic card
- 2 Audio Inputs

Is this possible to use these as sources in windows media foundation? If yes do i need special hardware?

Comment: @CPlusSharp is right.  MFEnumDeviceSource will automatically pick up the HDMI input ports from a capture card (providing it is a decent card with recent drivers) along with any input channels from your audio device(s), providing you call the function with the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For a second audio input you need a second sound card. The Audio devices should be available in Media Foundation. [`MFEnumDeviceSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/windows/desktop/dd388503.aspx)

I don't know any graphic card with an HDMI Input! For this, you need a special card/box from [BlackMagic](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/) or [Matrox](http://www.matrox.com/video/en/home/). But I don't know if these two have drivers for MediaFoundation. I only know that these two have DirectShow drivers.

Comment: While your answer is accurate (as I pointed out above), it is a bit more of a comment.